# Given a vector, apply a function to each element of another vector

Tags: r

**Question 1**

I have a function that takes in `p` and `n`. I need to graph every combination of `p=c(0.05,0.1,0.25,0.5,0.9,0.95)` and `n=c(5,10,30,50,100)`. So total of 6*5=30 plots. I've tried using `mapply` which returns a plot shown below (**EDIT: too low reputation to upload img but I shows I get 6 plots only**). Based on where my `ablines` are, I think it's trying all values of `p` over only a single value of `n`!

**Question 2**

I am trying to put values of `n` and `p` into the plot using `paste0()` to track which plot belongs to which combination of `n` and `p`, but it does not seem to work when I use `mapply` (it works fine for single graphs that I manually plot)

```
ci.auto <- function(p,n,alpha){

    # Repeat the process nsim times
    nsim <- 10000
    ci.mat <- replicate(nsim, conf.int(p, n, alpha))

    # Graphing the first 100 intervals

    matplot(rbind(1:100, 1:100), ci.mat[, 1:100], type = "l", lty = 1, 
            xlab = paste0("sample number n=",n), ylab = "confidence interval")
    abline(h = p)
    text(2.5, 0.8, paste0("p=",p), col = "red")

    # Proportion of times the interval is correct

    mean( (p >= ci.mat[1,])*(p <= ci.mat[2,]) )
}

par(mfrow = c(5,6))
mapply(ci.auto, p = c(0.05,0.1,0.25,0.5,0.9,0.95), n = c(5,10,30,50,100), alpha)
```

Comment: It's just a singular value of 0.05.

Comment: `mapply` iterates in parallel, so it's not creating the other combinations. Use `expand.grid` or `rep` to generate them, then pass the combinations to `mapply`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df<-expand.grid(p,n)
mapply(Fun = ci.auto, df$Var1,df$Var2,alpha)
```